# Vuforia 4 and unity 5 AR on touchscreen

Tags: augmented-reality, touchscreen, vuforia, unity-game-engine

I am completely new to AR. I created 3 markers using vuforia and unity and each display a 3d model. So far when I show a marker to my webcam it displays the 3d object. Now I have been trying to create on touchscreen function. I want that when the user seeing my 3d models, when he touches them a message pops up. I followed different tutorials from different forums and videos in youtube but none of them worked. Could you please help giving me a detailed description of what i need to do? or if there are any bugs in unity?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

1. Add colliders to your game object.
2. You need reference to the AR Camera.
3. Use the AR Camera to get the ray.
4. Use Raycast to get the hit object.

Just add this update code to some component in your scene:

```
// We need a reference to the AR Camera in the scene
public Camera ARCameraReference;

// Add this update code to any component
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Ray ray = ARCameraReference.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit : " + hit.collider.gameObject.name);

            // Do whatever you want from here
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

For your reference:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: Hi, so in this way I will know which object was hit with the mouse by their name. Since I have 3 different image targets with different 3d models (with different name).

Comment: Using mouse functions on mobile device is equivalent to touch, but single-touch only.